# strange encoding issue of a JSON file with json.loads

Tags: python, json, vim, utf-8

I have a JSON file that contains non-ascii characters, mostly spanish accentuated vowels. I've set the encoding of this file to be utf-8 (using vim and :set fileencoding=utf8).

An extract of this file, that can be used for reference:

```
[
  {
    "location": "SRID=4326;POINT(-1.7944444440000000 43.3798499999999976)",
    "description": "",
    "name": "Fuenterrabía",
    "_id": 162
  },
...
]
```

Notice the 'í' in the name field.

That said, I need to create an iterable of this elements in my code, so at the end I send it to the create method of a FactoryBoy Factory class. Thing is, in the process, the characters get messed up and I get the unfamous:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 143: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Having a look at the code that parses the file:

```
    def _get_spot_data(self, filename):
        data_file = str(settings.ROOT_DIR('fixtures/meteo/'+filename))
        # Open file with utf-8 encoding
        f = codecs.open(data_file, 'r', 'utf8')
        data = simplejson.loads(f.read(), 'utf-8')
        return data
```

Looking at the first position of the list (the one used for reference), I get this:

```
{u'_id': 162, u'location': u'SRID=4326;POINT(-1.7944444440000000 43.3798499999999976)', u'name': u'Fuenterrab\xeda', u'description': u''}
```

As you can see, it looks like I'm getting a byte representation of the 'í' character.

I've tried using only open instead of codecs.open, tried using json.loads instead of simplejson, but nothing works...what I'm doing wrong here???

**EDIT:** Tried to create a dummy entry to see if I was getting the same error...thus I guess something on FactorBoy is going wrong:

```
dummy_one = {u'surfspot_id': 162, u'location': u'SRID=4326;POINT(-1.7944444440000000 43.3798499999999976)', u'name': u'Fuenterrabía', u'description': u''}
SpotFactory(**dummy_one)
```

And the error is thrown again...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 76, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 156, in shouldRollover
    msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 143: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file base.py, line 397
```

I must say this is not a blocking issue, is just a warning exception, but I don't like to see it, would like the output to be clean

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that 'loads' raises an exception UnicodeDecodeError? If so, then what is the example you are giving "looking at the first position of the list..."? Is it not a result of 'loads'?

Comment: Nope. that is raised afterwards by the create method from a Factory I have from FactoryBoy, but it is the result of passing the byte representation of the unicode character 'í'...

Comment: Side question Does your JSON file have a BOM?

Comment: @Tomalak you mean the enconding at the beginning of file? Nope it doesn't, I've used vim to specify character encoding for that file...do I need a BOM yes or yes?

Comment: No, you absolutely don't, it's possible but the wrong thing to set a BOM for UTF-8 files. vim has an option for that (`:h bomb`), you can set it separately from `fenc`, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

This works well:

```
import json

with open(r'your/data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f, encoding='utf-8')
    name = data[0]['name']

    print name
    print len(name)
    print name[-2:-1]
```

prints:

```
Fuenterrabía
12
í
```

---

However, this

```
print data[0]
```

is still printed as:

```
{
    u'_id': 162, 
    u'location': u'SRID=4326;POINT(-1.7944444440000000 43.3798499999999976)',
    u'name': u'Fuenterrab\xeda', 
    u'description': u''
}
```

Don't let yourself be fooled by that output, the string itself is Unicode and contains the proper character.

Comment: Thanks, but then why the _create method from factory/django.py does fail? The exception is thrown and when I pass the dictionary as above...

Comment: I don't know. Does it accept the data when you hand-craft a dummy it in the Python script instead of retrieving it from the JSON file?

Comment: Yup, looks very much like a problem in FactoryBoy.